Tool to modernize C89 codebase
I am working on a codebase that was written in C89.
That means that all function-local variables - even in nested scopes - are declared at the top of the function.
I would like to modernize this codebase - preferably automatically - and move the variable declarations where they are first assigned or, in the case of a variable assigned in two distinct branches, immediately before the branches.
Does someone know about a tool that can achieve this?

There is nothing wrong with having the declarations at the top of the function & some coding standards still insist on it regardless of the C version used as it maximises compiler portability while minimises the refactoring as the code changes over time, (e.g. if a new branch is introduced that impacts a given variable that was declared on a single branch you will not need to move the declaration). Personally I would recommend only changing functions that you are already modifying.

As Steve said, if it aint' broke, don;t fix it. Whatever you do, run static code anylisis on it, and add uni ttets until you have 100% code coverage. Both of those will add way more that shuffling declaraions.
